# Find user stories for specific release or project

Tags: rest, url, rally

I need to know how to import user stories for the project I am working on and filter those user stories using specific releases that some of them connected to 
Actually I need something using the url to fitch this data like :

[https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v3.0/artifact?query=((Release.Name=.............))=&fetch=true](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v3.0/artifact?query=%28%28Release.Name=.............%29%29=&fetch=true)

but it is not filtering the data using the release name

also If I can modify this one to get the data that will be fine :

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v3.0/hierarchicalrequirement/?fetch=Release,Tasks,FormattedID,Name,Owner,State&start=1&pagesize=200&pretty=true

Answer (score 0):

Per [WS API object model](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/), there is no Release attribute on Artifact.

Use `hierarchicalrequirement` instead of `artifact`:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(Release.Name%20%3D%20%22ReleaseABC%22)&fetch=FormattedID,ScheduleState&pagesize=200
```

Since you are fetching Tasks: as long as you are interested only in the reference to the collection and the count it is sufficient. If you want to hydrate the collection a separate request is needed. In this example we traverse WorkProduct.ObjectID:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task?query=(WorkProduct.ObjectID%20%3D%12345)&fetch=State,ToDo,Estimate&pagesize=200
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats work . Do you know how I can search for the user stories under specific project ?

Comment: Yes. You may use Project.Name similar to Release.Name. Experiment in the interactive WS API documentation.